# Set min and max width of Rectangle

Tags: actionscript-3, prezi

How can I set a range in AS3 for value of (for example) width of my screen?
What I mean is I have this piece of code:

```
var myBounds:Rectangle=this.getBounds(stage);
if ((myBounds.width>650)&&(visibleArea.intersects(myBounds)))
{

  if(this.currentFrame==1)
     this.play();
}
else
{
    this.gotoAndStop(1);
}
return;
```

and my movie starts only if it's width more than 650 px.
What I don't know is how to set a range of values, something like this:
250<.width<650, so my movie will start only if it's width between this numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (stage.loaderInfo.width < 650 && stage.loaderInfo.width > 250) {
    play();
} else {
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

You'll have to call the function at some sort of interval, either by event or by enterframe.

Comment: Thank you, I did what I want.

Comment: Awesome.  Don't forget to accept the answer so others know the issue is resolved.